# SSIS File Transfer task use a wrong cipher

Tags: ssis, ftps, cozyroc

I'm using CozyRoc 1.6 and I am trying to connect to an FTPS (TLS1.2) using the connection below:

```
ConnectionType=ImplicitTLS;ServerHost=SERVER;ServerPort=990;ServerUser=USER;ServerPassword=PASSWORD;ServerTimeout=60;CertificateFile=;LogFile=;PassiveMode=True;PassiveIgnoreAddress=False;Ciphertype=all;
```

It gives handshake error and it is because the host does not support the cipher it is using. I tried Ciphertype but it doesn't work with any of the options.

Comment: SSIS doesn't support FTPS by default. You'll need a 3rd party utility. CozyRoc and KingsWaySoft both make SSIS components you can add to your SSIS toolbox. You can also use something like the FileZilla command line client, and then call that with an `Execute Process Task`, perhaps.

Comment: right Im using cozyroc 1.6

Comment: Cane you post the exact error message you're getting? Also, did you mean to leave off the `CertificateFile` value and `LogFile` value? Do you have a client certificate file for the TLS connection?